# making the intervals and calculating their frequencies in R

Tags: r, frequency

How I can define several intervals from a continuous (suppose speed) variable when class size is 0.1 and add a new variable to the data set regarding the frequency of observations in each level. The min value of speed is 4 and the max is 25.

```
library(stat)
Data(cars)
```

So I want to have something like `(4 to 4.1) (4.1 to 4.2) (4.2 to 4.3) ...(24.9 to 25)` then I need to see how many values of speed are inside of each of these intervals (frequency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're essentially asking for a histogram of your data.  You can use the hist() function and change "breaks =" to define different interval lengths. Additional reading: https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-make-a-histogram-with-basic-r/

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, I want to make a new variable from speed by considering length size= o.1 so I will have  (1 to  1.1) (1.1 to 1.2) (1.2 to 1.3) and then I want to calculate the frequency of observation in each interval (add new variable into the data set).

Comment: You're looking for 'seq'.  seq(-1, 2, by = .1) is an example

Comment: @ Raag Agrawal, I want to make different intervals. The length of each interval is 0.1. It means if the min value of speed is 4 the first interval would be 4 to 4.1 the next interval would be 4.1 to 4.2 and we continue till to get the last interval which includes the max value of speed and then I want to see frequency number of each interval.

Comment: You need to create breaks = seq(4,100, by=0.5) and then use duration.cut = cut(duration, breaks, right=FALSE).  And then duration.freq = table(duration.cut).  This will give you a set of breaks, and then cut your data by the breaks established.  Then the table() function will give you frequency

Comment: @ Raag Agrawal , great, thanks so much, how can I change the structure of  duration.freq to a data frame.

Comment: just do as.dataframe() ??

Comment: yes, It works and the last question, How i can calculate the midpoint of each interval?

Comment: no idea honestly.  I would just assume 0.05 increments are the midpoints.  google around.  I would appreciate approving my answer!